# White Space Between Wrapper & Div

Tags: php, html, css

I'm relatively new to web designing, and this is my first full-scale project so I apologize in advance if any of my code is found messy. Cutting straight to the point, I'd like to make the space between my main content/wrapper and footer a specific size. By which I mean cutting the space at the end of the page to about 20px. My code/css would be too long to explain, so I'm wondering if anyone familiar with FF's element modifier would take a look and see if they can figure out what's causing the large gap.

Link to my website: http://guard.neetgroup.net/?

This is the homepage for some reason, with nothing in the main content bar:
[image]

Another accessible pages w/o login:

http://guard.neetgroup.net/?app=cpanel

http://guard.neetgroup.net/?app=profile&u=Veritas

http://guard.neetgroup.net/?page=404

Comment: Updated the main post, I'm trying to cut the gap to 20px on every page.

Comment: Setting `height:100%` on a div will cause that div to be as high as the window. This will _always_ give you a scroll bar. This is probably wrong. Also, your _copyright_ character is not encoded right (I see the diamond placeholder). Use `&copy;` to use the HTML entity form and not bother with encoding.

Comment: I was using height:100% for the sticky footer prior, I attempted removing it, and it didn't make a difference. As for the copyright, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the 100% height on the wrapper, and padding out relative length of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Made some slight changes to your css and i think i got what you needed.

`CSS`

```
div#wrapper.global {
margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
```

Then remove the footer with the id gap as it's not needed and remove the height in the body.

This makes the footer only 20px under the content box but doesnt extend the footers background colour to the bottom of the page. To do that, you would really need to recode the website again and use the footer bg as the body background and have the header and content use different background colours as theyll be the expanding content in the middle.